# android 4 : tunneling whole device to a proxy

Tags: java, android, proxy

(by proxy I mean HTTP proxy)

I wanted to make an application which works like [psiphon3](http://psiphon3.com)

in tunneling whole device through proxy without root needed

first please tell me how this tunneling method works, then how can I write a program that works like that for example tunneling device on proxy : localhost:8118

if psiphon isn't tunneling device through proxy then how does it work ?

- just for android 4 (and without root)